# Will @NonNull give an error on using @NoArgsConstructor?

Tags: java, lombok

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Company {

    @NonNull
    private String location;
    
    @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

Now if I write something like -

1. `Company company = new Company();`
2. `company.setLocation("Florida");`
3. `company.setName("ABC");`

**Question 1** - On line 1 would I get an error, as a new object is created but location and name are null and they are annotated with `@NonNull`?

**Question 2** - Would I get any errors on lines 2 and 3?

Comment: Can't you simply try and see what happens?

Comment: Which `@NonNull` annotation ,as that is quite important to what might happen.

Comment: Facing some issues with my IDE. Also would like some background about the working of @NonNull. That's why I asked

Comment: @M.Deinum Either one of them?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85 Sure. Actually they are part of a single question only, It's just that I have broken them down for clarity

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is the full name (including the package) of the `@NonNull` annotation. Which one is used. Without knowing which annotation it is, that question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum lombok.NonNull

Comment: Then the answer is no and no as you aren't assigning `null` to the fields. If you do `setName(null)` it will throw an exception. As explained by the [lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull)

Comment: One additional question - If I use a builder annotation and only set the name but not the location will a NPE(Null Pointer Exception) be thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated, because the java community deals with null in different ways, and 'non null' means different things: For example, in a DB model class it can mean: The `CREATE TABLE` statement that the DB framework generates if you ask it to make the tables for you should add a NOT NULL constraint in the SQL. However, as the POJO is also supposed to be capable of representing a half-built row (for example, where the unid field, which represents the unid column in your database, holds `null` because the whole point is to let the DB use its auto-sequence to fill it in, which won't happen until you `save()` it, therefore java-side that field can and usually *is* null!

Thus, lombok's NonNull support has 4 aspects to it which are all very very different:

### `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`, as well as all lombok features that imply one of those (`@Builder`, `@Data`, and `@Value`).

Lombok treats any field that is either `final` **or** has some sort of `NonNull` annotation that it recognizes specifically as implying that no object should ever even exist where this field is null (which notably **excludes** JPA's NotNull!), and which is configurable in `lombok.config` but lombok ships with a decent known set of annotations out of the box, as 'required'.

A 'required' field has the following properties:

1. `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will make a parameter for it.
2. The constructors made by `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` will null-check these fields using the nullcheck mechanism as configured in your lombok.config. By default, it's: `if (x == null) throw new NullPointerException("x");`.

### `@NoArgsConstructor`

This one is built different. NoArgsConstructor **adds no null checks**. It would be completely pointless: If lombok was supposed to add them, then that means the only right answer is that lombok makes this constructor for you:

```
public YourType() {
    throw new NullPointerException("NameOfFirstFieldMarkedNonNull");
}
```

which seems like a pointless exercise.

So, instead, lombok leaves those fields as null and assumes you know what you are doing. Generally you make these constructors either because a framework requires that you do so, or because a framework will 'fix' the problem of having fields marked as never null containing a null value by immediately invoking a bunch of setters or reflectively updating those fields.

### `@Setter` as well as lombok features that imply it (`@Data`).

These will null-check the argument in the same way.

### `@lombok.NonNull` on a parameter

Unlike the previous stuff, this feature works ONLY for `lombok.NonNull` and not for any other non-null annotations: This will add a nullcheck at the top of your method.

The reason lombok doesn't do this for others is that it's conflicting: If you consider `@NonNull` as a type annotation, then it's saying: This value cannot possibly be null, it's guaranteed, which inverses the nature of it: Now a null check is a compiler error/warning!

It's like writing:

```
public void foo(String x) {
    if (x != null && !(x instanceof String)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x is not a string");
}
```

That should be a compiler error/warning as it can't happen and is just useless code. If you work in a very strict nullity system that is ruthlessly checked by your compiler, `@NonNull` can imply the same thing, thus, we don't just add that null check.

### `@Builder`

Yes, that will throw NPE. That's because `@Builder` on a class is just syntax sugar for: `@AllArgsConstructor` (which will throw NPEs if a parameter is null for a field that is marked NonNull), and then put `@Builder` on that all-args constructor. So, the builder doesn't null check, but the builder's `.build()` call will call that constructor, and it will.